# Multiple occurrence of custom CompositeUserType in Hibernate causing MappingException

Tags: java, hibernate, usertype

Hi I have the following code:

```
public class Trail {
    private int trailID;
    private Location startLocation;
    private Location destination;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

which Location is a custom DB type, it's not a table

```
public class LocationType implements org.hibernate.usertype.CompositeUserType {
    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index, SessionImplementor session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        if ( value == null ) {
            DoubleType.INSTANCE.set(st, null, index, session);
            DoubleType.INSTANCE.set(st, null, index+1, session);
            DoubleType.INSTANCE.set(st, null, index+2, session);
            StringType.INSTANCE.set(st, null, index+3, session);
        } else {
            final Location loc = (Location) value;
            DoubleType.INSTANCE.set(st, loc.getLatitude(), index, session);
            DoubleType.INSTANCE.set(st, loc.getLongitude(), index+1, session);
            DoubleType.INSTANCE.set(st, loc.getAltitude(), index+2, session);
            StringType.INSTANCE.set(st, loc.getDescription(), index+3, session);
        }
    }

    // Other functions
}
```

and this is my Location class

```
public class Location implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

The Trail.hbm.xml looks like this:

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.mytest.walking">
    <class name="Trail" table="TB_Trail" dynamic-insert="true">
        <id name="TrailID" column="TrailID" >
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="StartLocation" type="LocationType" >
            <column name="latitude" />
            <column name="longitude" />
            <column name="altitude" />
            <column name="description" />
        </property>
        <property name="Destination" type="LocationType" >
            <column name="latitude" />
            <column name="longitude" />
            <column name="altitude" />
            <column name="description" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Then I got the following exception

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: property mapping has wrong number of columns: com.mytest.walking.Trail.Destination type: com.mytest.walking.LocationType
        at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:468)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:268)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1287)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1729)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1775)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:184)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:314)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
```

Can someone point me to the right direction on how to get rid of this exception?

Comment: does it work if you remove one Location property from the hbm?

Answer (score 0):

why not use a componentmapping

```
<component name="StartLocation" >
    <property name="..." column="latitude" />
    <property name="..." column="longitude" />
    <property name="..." column="altitude" />
    <property name="..." column="description" />
</property>
<component name="Destination" >
    <property name="..." column="latitude" />
    <property name="..." column="longitude" />
    <property name="..." column="altitude" />
    <property name="..." column="description" />
</property>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I would like to use usertype instead of component if possible.  Because while this would work for the case, the location type is being used in other tables as well.  And I just don't want to repeat the columns (latitude, longitude, altitude, description etc) in all these tables.

Comment: but you have to repeat the column names nonetheless, see the code you posted. A usertype only specifies the types of the columns but not theire names

Comment: or you switch to mapping annotations or use .NET and FluentNHibernate where you can map the component once and reference it in the mappings

Comment: Thanks for the help Firo, I think I got the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  Just name the columns differently.  They don't need to be same as the custom type name.

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.mytest.walking">
    <class name="Trail" table="TB_Trail" dynamic-insert="true">
        <id name="TrailID" column="TrailID" >
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="StartLocation" type="LocationType" >
            <column name="StartLocationLatitude" />
            <column name="StartLocationLongitude" />
            <column name="StartLocationAltitude" />
            <column name="StartLocationDescription" />
        </property>
        <property name="Destination" type="LocationType" >
            <column name="DestinationLatitude" />
            <column name="DestinationLongitude" />
            <column name="DestinationAltitude" />
            <column name="DestinationDescription" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: right that helps. i still would go with component since you dont need the whole customusertype